# The add(E e) method in Collection<E>&Queue<E>&BlockingQueue<E> interfaces

Tags: java, collections

Question 1:

When reading JDK source codes I found that method `boolean add(E e);` defined in interface `Collection<E>`&`Queue<E>`&`BlockingQueue<E>` .

I cannot understand this. In my understanding if a super interface has defined a method, then a sub interface extending this super interface need not to define this method again.

So why has this method been defined three times?

Question 2:

Also I noticed that unlike the `boolean add(E e);` method which has been claimed in interface `Queue<E>` and then re-claimed in interface `BlockingQueue<E>`, the  `E poll();` method has been only claimed in interface `Queue<E>` and has not been re-claimed in interface `BlockingQueue<E>`.

So why are they treated differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: When reading JDK source codes I found  boolean add(E e); defined in interface Collection&Queue&BlockingQueue .
>
> I cannot understand this. In my understanding if a super interface has defined a method, then a sub interface extending this super interface need not to define this method again.

Yes, you don't need to redefine it. I'd guess it's probable because you'd need to repeat the declaration in order to add new JavaDoc comments, i.e. each of the interfaces has a specific description of what `add(E)` etc. do.

> Question 2: also I noticed that unlike the boolean add(E e); method which has been claimed in interface Queue and then re-claimed in interface BlockingQueue, the  E poll(); method has been only claimed in interface Queue and has not been re-claimed in interface BlockingQueue.
>
> So why they are treated differently?

It's probably the same as above. `poll(E)` works the same way for general queues and blocking ones, hence no need for a different documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**The difference here is only on the documentation.** The `E poll()` method signature was not mentioned in the `BlockingQueue` because the contract is the same for both `Queue` and `BlockingQueue` and the documentation for both explains the behaviour of the 2 data structure to be the same.

If you look at the documentation of `Queue.add()` and `BlockingQueue.add()`, you will see an additional sentence added on `BlockingQueue.add()` method.

`Queue.add()`:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do
>   so immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning true
>   upon success and throwing an IllegalStateException if no space is
>   currently available.

`BlockingQueue.add()`:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do
>   so immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning true
>   upon success and throwing an `IllegalStateException` if no space is
>   currently available. When using a capacity-restricted queue, it is
>   generally preferable to use `offer`.

This is to help developers when using the relevant object.

Technically, the `add()` method are the same so `BlockingQueue` never needed to explicitly specify that method signature.

Comment: I don't think it's the additional sentence in the main text on add() (which seems to be missing in your quotes btw) but the different description of the exceptions, e.g. `throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this queue does not permit null elements` on `Queue` while the same description on `BlockingQueue` misses the second part since it doesn't accept nulls at all.

Comment: what's the difference between `and this queue does not permit null elements` and without it?  If a NullPointerException is thrown, it also will not permit null element right ？

Comment: @ZhaoGang it means that there might be a `Queue` object that allows `null`. If, by design, it doesn't allow `null`, then it must throw a `NullPointerException`. Any `BlockingQueue` object cannot accept a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more to do with defining the behavior of what is expected from the method to behave. Technically, there is no need to defined add in the Queue or Blocking Queue but since the behaviour of add can be different depending on whether Collection is a Set or Queue, it's much better to re-define it so that people can understand what exactly is expected from Queue add method.

So, as long as behavior is not supposed to change or enhance, there is no need to declare the method in sub-interface but if you expect the behavior to be specific than you should go ahead and re-declare it.